# Spring AOP : Aspect around a method returning ResponseBodyEmitter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I've create a custom annotation to perform double-check on controller responses.
The annotation is working fine for blocking controllers.
However for non-blocking controllers which are returning `ResponseBodyEmitter`, I didn't find out how to get response and perform checks.

Any solution ?

```
@Around("@annotation(foo.bar.CustomAnnotation)")
public Object handleCustomAnnotation(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

    ResponseEntity response = (ResponseEntity) pjp.proceed();

    if (response != null && response.hasBody()) {
        Object body = response.getBody();
        if (body instanceof ResponseBodyEmitter) {
            ResponseBodyEmitter rbe = (ResponseBodyEmitter) body;
           // How to get or subscribe to the response emitter ? 
        }else{
          // Performs checks for blocking controllers --> Works fine !
        }
      }
      return response;
   }
```

Even [`onCompletion`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyEmitter.html#onCompletion-java.lang.Runnable-) doesn't provide any consumer on the emitted data.

Thanks

Comment: @kriegaex do you have any idea ? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I am an AOP expert, but not a Spring user. Your question is entirely Spring-specific. That there is no API on the server side to consume the response, should give you a hint that is it not meant to be. It is to be streamed into an output channel for the client to consume it. If Spring has means to intercept something there, it must be in another place. You could of course extend `ResponseBodyEmitter`, make the subclass a Spring bean and intercept the `send` method in order to inspect what is meant to be sent.